# Are there common Stylus "libraries"

Tags: javascript, css, stylus

seems like most of what I wish to do with `stylus`, for example,

```
border-radius()
  -webkit-border-radius arguments
  -moz-border-radius arguments
  border-radius arguments
```

should be pretty common with what others are doing.

are there common `stylus` "libraries" being used?

Comment: https://github.com/visionmedia/nib

Comment: @JonathanOng - looks perfect, thanks.  please post as answer so can close question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Jonathan mentioned in a comment, the best answer is “[nib](https://github.com/visionmedia/nib)” — it's the lib from the one of the Stylus' developers, and there are a lot of people contributing to it.

Answer (score 2):

For something with grids and elements (in addition to mixins), there's also [axis](http://roots.cx/axis/), which may end up being merged with nib.